# Ring homomorphisms inducing same map on their affine schemes

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $f,g:R \to S$ be ring homomorphisms between commutative rings $R,S$.
Suppose that  there are unit elements of $R$ and $S$ and we denote the units by $r \in R,s \in S$, i.e there are some $r' \in R,s' \in S$ such that $rr' =1,ss'=1$.

If$f(x) = s \times g(r \times x), x \in R$, then $f,g$ induce same map on $\operatorname{Spec} S \to \operatorname{Spec} R$. Is there other possibility that ring homomorphism inducing same map on their spectrums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of algebraic geometry our rings are all unital rings and ring homomorphisms should send $1\mapsto 1$. So in the $f,g$ you have in your question you are getting $f(1)=s\cdot g(r\cdot 1)=s\cdot g(r)$ which need not equal $1$, so this $f$ isn't actually a ring homomorphism unless $s=g(r)^{-1}$ but in this case you are getting $f=g$ anyways.

Thus, I am going to interpret your question as follows:

> **Question**: What are examples of different ring homomorphisms $R\to S$ inducing the same map $\operatorname{Spec}(S)\to\operatorname{Spec}(R)$?

Here are some typical examples that come to mind:

- If you take a field $F$ with a nontrivial automorphism $\sigma:F\to F$, then $\sigma$ and the identity $\mathrm{id}_F$ are different ring homomorphisms, but $\operatorname{Spec}(F)$ consists of a single point so they must induce the same map $\operatorname{Spec}(F)\to\operatorname{Spec}(F)$.
- If $R$ is a ring of characteristic $p$ then one has the Frobenius $\phi:R\to R$ sending $r\mapsto r^p$. You can check this induces the identity on $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ so as long as $\phi\neq\mathrm{id}_R$ for your ring $R$ you have that these are distinct homomorphisms inducing the same map on $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$.

Comment: I gotcha. In your last example,                                                                                                                                           (1)$\phi$ is homomorphism. In fact, using characteristic $p$, $\phi(x+y) =(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p = \phi(x) +\phi(y)$ for  $x,y \in R$.                                   
(2) For any prime ideal $P$, $x^p \in P$ is equivalent to $x \in P$, so, $\phi^{-1}P =P$. Thanks.